# Does juicing make fiber digestible?

Tags: fruit, fiber, juice

I was just talking with a nutritionist who told me that

> when you mechanically blend a fruit you make the fiber become more
>   digestible to your body

Hence you lose a little bit of the benefit of just eating the whole fruit.

is this true?
please provide a source that backs your opinion

Comment: This question is off-topic as it does not relate to exercise as stated in the [faq].

Comment: are you serious?.. then just change the name of the stackexchange site to just fitness... remove the Nutrition part.. cause if the words "fiber" and "digestible" are not related in your mind to Nutrition maybe you shouldnt be an admin.

Comment: This has been [discussed before](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/137/reviewing-the-site-scope-balance-between-fitness-and-nutrition) and we have brought up on expanding the scope to [sports](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/86/should-the-scope-be-expanded-to-fitness-sports). It's still an ongoing topic that members of the community [have been discussing](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/96/sports-se-and-fn-se-should-be-merged).

Comment: expanding the scope to sports would not make my question to be on-topic though... it's the word nutrition that's key here. does my question relate to nutrition?

Comment: Your question is nutrition related, but the faq states that "nutrition unrelated to exercise, such as food safety, nutritional needs for children, etc." is off-topic. "Nutrition as it relates to exercise" is on-topic for this site so if you rephrased your question in this context, I would be willing to reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accourding to the following, blending has no effect on fiber content per say.

http://www.oprah.com/health/Does-Blending-Fruit-Reduce-Its-Fiber-Content

Like the article says, the main issue, is that you digest a liquid faster than you do a solid. This is probably what your nutritionist means when she says the fiber becomes "more digestable".

However, there is still the same amount of fiber in your smoothie as there is in a whole fruit.

Comment: I find it hilarious that you assumed "she" for my nutritionist.

Comment: Wow I didn't even notice that... I feel ashamed :(